# non blocking Matcher find

Tags: java, regex

I have a code that is like this:-

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\\{(.*?)\\}\\{)|(\\{(.*?)\\}$))");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str); 
int pos = 0;

while(true)
{
    if(matcher.find(pos))
    {
        ...
        pos--;
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

What I am seeing is that matcher.find(pos) gets blocked if a pattern match doesnot happen. How to avoid this blocking nature and have it come out if there is no match in the input string.

Comment: What's your input String? This should not be happening. Are you sure the `...` isn't making you loop indefinitely?

Answer (score 1):

It does not block but loops infinitely depending on str content. If you find a match at pos = 1 then pos-- returns matcher in the initial state (to pos = 0) and this causes an infinite loop

Comment: The `Matcher` throws an [exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find(int)) if its `start` parameter (`pos`) is negative. If we ignore the `...`, `pos` can only be negative after the first time it loops.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you are looking for something like this. I'm guessing you are trying to find each pattern in your input string(str). Please see code comments for implementation.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PatternTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String str = "{test1}{test2}{test3}{test4}";

      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\\{(.*?)\\}\\{)|(\\{(.*?)\\}$))");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
      int pos = 0;

      while (true)
      {
         if (matcher.find(pos))
         {
            System.out.println("MATCH START: " + matcher.start());
            System.out.println("MATCH END: " + matcher.end());
            System.out.println("MATCH GROUP: " + matcher.group());
            System.out.println();

            // Move position to end of MATCH
            pos = matcher.end()-1;
         }
         else if(matcher.hitEnd())
         {
            // Break when matcher hit end
            break;
         }
         else
         {
            // No Match YET - Move position 1
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
            pos++;
         }
      }
   }
}
```